# Transaction From Ethereum Smart contract

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, cryptocurrency, ether

When we have a contract, we transfer currency

How is the signature done ???

For example, I send 10 ethers to the contract and the contract is divided between 5 people

What is this transaction like?  Where does my private key come from to sign all 5 transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I send 10 ethers to the contract and the contract is divided between 5 people*

So possibly something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function redistribute(address[5] memory otherPeople) external payable {
        for(uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            payable(otherPeople[i]).transfer(msg.value / 5);
        }
    }
}
```

You send one transaction (valued 10 ETH) to the contract, executing the `redistribute()` function.

The contract performs 5 internal transactions, effectively transferring 2 ETH to each of the `otherPeople` addresses.

In this case, you only need to use the private key of the "main" transaction sender, because the other transactions are internal txs, wrapped by the main tx.